# Change href in another PHP page using a variable

Tags: php

I'm brand new to this and trying to scab together two different ideas. Each of them work individually, but I'm trying to integrate them.

1. I am able to upload and image (which creates a list itme with an href="javascript:void(0).
2. I can allow user input to assign a url to an existing text link.

what I'm trying to do is target the dynamically created list item in the upload.php page and change the href="javascript:void(0) to the user specified variable from index.php

index.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>image upload</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#images').on('change',function(){
        $('#multiple_upload_form').ajaxForm({
            target:'#images_preview',
            beforeSubmit:function(e){
                $('.uploading').show();
            },
            success:function(e){
                $('.uploading').hide();
            },
            error:function(e){
            }
        }).submit();
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div class="upload_div" >
    <form name="multiple_upload_form" id="multiple_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="image_form_submit" value="1"/>
            <label>Choose Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple >
        <div class="uploading none">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <img src="uploading.gif"/>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery" id="images_preview">

    </div>

</div>
<div class="form_div" id="url_input">
<form id="form1">
URL - example http://www.yourdomain.com: <input name="name" type="text" size="20">
</form>
<button onclick="outputname()">Submit</button>
<script>

function outputname() {
var x,y,name,a,b,answer;
x=document.getElementById("form1") ;
y=x.elements["name"].value;
document.getElementById("upload.php#web").setAttribute("href",y);

}

</script>

<p id="demo">

<a id="link">this is a link</a>

</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php code

```
    <?php
if($_POST['image_form_submit'] == 1)
{
    $images_arr = array();
    foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key=>$val){
        $image_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
        $tmp_name   = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $size       = $_FILES['images']['size'][$key];
        $type       = $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];
        $error      = $_FILES['images']['error'][$key];

        ############ Remove comments if you want to upload and stored images into the "uploads/" folder #############

        /*$target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key],$target_file)){
            $images_arr[] = $target_file;
        }*/

        //display images without stored
        $extra_info = getimagesize($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key]);
        $images_arr[] = "data:" . $extra_info["mime"] . ";base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key]));
    }

    //Generate images view
    if(!empty($images_arr)){ $count=0;
        foreach($images_arr as $image_src){ $count++?>
            <ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">
                <li id="image_li_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="ui-sortable-handle">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="float:none;" class="image_link"><img src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" alt=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    <?php }
    }
}
?>
```

Like I said, I'm brand new to this and there may be a far more elegant solution, but I've gotten this far from just hunting and pecking... thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: > image (which creates a *what*?

Comment: oops... i had a tag listed and it killed the rest after... sorry, should have been clearer... trying to make the image a clickable link based on the user input (i.e. url, sms, phone, etc.)

Comment: got it.... just needed to move the user input code to the other page...